# The index outside of the range Exception

Tags: exception, sqldatareader

I'm trying to fill my list on Visual Studio side with help of stored procedure.

I'm using the following stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetColletcion]
AS
BEGIN   
         select  CollectionType.Name ,GlassesCollection.Name 
    from    GlassesCollection
    inner join CollectionType
    on GlassesCollection.CollectionType=CollectionType.CollTypeID
END
```

Here's the code-behind:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            List<GlassesCollection> list = new List<GlassesCollection>();
            using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Server=(local);DataBase=ISeeOptic;Integrated Security=SSPI"))
            {

                GlassesCollection gln = new GlassesCollection();
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
                SqlDataReader reader;

                cmd.Connection = conn;
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                cmd.CommandText = "GetColletcion";

                conn.Open();
                reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                  while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        gln.Name = (string)reader["CollectionType.Name"];
                        gln.CollectionType = (string)reader["GlassesCollection.Name"];

                        list.Add(gln);
                    }


                reader.Close();
                conn.Close();
            }

        }
```

But when it comes to this row:

```
gln.Name = (string)reader["CollectionType.Name"];
```

I get this Exception:

```
Exception Details: System.IndexOutOfRangeException: CollectionType.Name
```

The index outside of the range, although in database more than one record.
How can I solve my problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be best to use column aliases and refer to the columns by those instead.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetColletcion]
AS
BEGIN   
         select  CollectionType.Name As TypeName ,GlassesCollection.Name As GlassesName
    from    GlassesCollection
    inner join CollectionType
    on GlassesCollection.CollectionType=CollectionType.CollTypeID
END
```

Then use

```
(string)reader["TypeName"];
(string)reader["GlassesName"];
```

If you cannot change your stored procedure, then you can use the oridinal position:

```
(string)reader[0]; //CollectionType.Name
(string)reader[1]; //GlassesCollection.Name
```

Comment: I have make chenges on my stored procedure and it's work properly.But i cant understand what the problem with my code?why it dosent work?

Comment: With your original code you were returning two columns with the same name. When SQL returns the result back to the client it only returns the name of the column, not the table and column. If you were to loop through all the field names you'd notice two instances of "Name". If you were to have accessed reader["Name"], it would have returned only the first matching column's data.

Answer (score 1):

I corrected your typo, too. (GetCollection)

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetCollection]
AS
BEGIN   
         select  CollectionType.Name AS CollectionType_Name, GlassesCollection.Name AS GlassesCollection_Name 
    from    GlassesCollection
    inner join CollectionType
    on GlassesCollection.CollectionType=CollectionType.CollTypeID
END
```

Code behind:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        List<GlassesCollection> list = new List<GlassesCollection>();
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Server=(local);DataBase=ISeeOptic;Integrated Security=SSPI"))
        {

            GlassesCollection gln = new GlassesCollection();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
            SqlDataReader reader;

            cmd.Connection = conn;
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.CommandText = "GetCollection";

            conn.Open();
            reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
              while (reader.Read())
                {
                    gln.Name = (string)reader["GlassesCollection_Name"];
                    gln.CollectionType = (string)reader["CollectionType_Name"];

                    list.Add(gln);
                }


            reader.Close();
            conn.Close();
        }

    }
```